# PHP, JSON and \u-somethings

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I'm using php 5.2. My file and db table are utf8.

when i insert a column with json_encoded data in it, it converts non-ascii chars into \u-something. ok. when i json_decode the data those \u-somethings are still there!

wasn't json_decode supposed to convert back to the normal chars when displaying on a utf8 page. For example, instead of f\u00f6tter, it should display fötter. do i have to use another function for conversion?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html

Answer (score 2):

json_encode and json_decode are kind of weak in PHP. Both do the minimum to produce valid, but not necessarily the intended output. json_decode has no idea if \u00f6 is supposed to be `ö` or `\u00f6`. There is no way to make json_decode aggressively convert unicode characters back. Remember that JSON is designed to be directly eval'able by JavaScript, and JavaScript will evaluate those escapings.

But why are you json encoding your data to store it in MySQL?

Comment: "JSON is designed to be directly eval'able by JavaScript" .. that is not true, that is only the quick & dirty way to parse JSON; for a real JSON parser, see json.org. JSON output

Comment: That was the original design, but it evolved almost immediately. It's certainly not the recommended way to parse JSON, I agree.

Comment: Mark because objects in db have a lot of settings per object. json is kinda storing all in one. i have a question too. Do you know for sure that json_decode does not convert back?

Comment: Why not use [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) and [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize)? Those functions will convert PHP arrays to strings and back perfectly.

Comment: yes probably. if there is no other way in json_* funcs in php. json have the obvious advantage but anyway

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old question but the answer did not really answer the question for me.

eventually, i was able to get what i wanted using the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag.

`$output = json_encode($input, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

caveat:  this only works if you are able to store utf8 in your database; you said your table is utf8 so that should be ok.  i was not able to find a way to convert the \u strings back at decode time, so encoding it as unescaped utf8 is what worked for me.

also, if you're using PHP 7.1+ (your post said 5.2 but that was a long time ago) then you may want to add the JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS flag as well)